What type of thinner for cleaning brushes used in two part polyurethane?
I am painting with Epifanes two part polyurethane. The Epifanes thinner Is very expensive. Can I use other thinners?

If you will be using the brushes again tomorrow, then wrap them tightly in a plastic bag with a capful of thinners. They keep overnight for use the next day.
Did this when using 2-pack Rustoleum and the brushes lasted several days. Then we cleaned them thoroughly, mind you the brushes were top quality...

In the US, Klean Strip brush cleaner (the one in the metal can, not the plastic milky stuff) does the job and is relatively cheap. Elsewhere in the world, gasoline.
